# Is systemctl reload bareos-dir and bacula-dir the same as running reload in the bconsole?

Tags: systemd, bacula, bareos

In a course I'm taking on Bacula/Bareos, the instructor states that running `sudo systemctl restart bareos-dir` will stop (and ruin) any running backup jobs when an op does this to update the configuration.  And instead the instructor states that on a production system, an op should go into the bconsole and run the `reload` command to update the configuration without harming any jobs that are currently running.

So considering this, does running `sudo systemctl reload bareos-dir` do the same thing as running `reload` in the bconsole; does it reload the configuration without harming any currently running backups?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. However it is recommended to run it from `bconsole`as it will show you errors if there's something wrong with your new config

*Update*:

- Tip1. Run `echo reload | bconsole` to avoid connecting to bconsole. It will still show stdout from `bconsole` in your tty
- Tip2. Run `echo messages | bconsole` to show any logged messages